# drawing objects on pygame

Tags: python, pygame, drawing, simulation

I am restarting some code for a covid simulation as I cant use the collide function in my current one. I have been able to draw the basic background, and draw one cell. However, when i try create the cell in a different place on my screen it does not appear for some reason.

My code is as seen below:

```
import random
import pygame
# import numpy
import time

pygame.init()

GREEN1 = (0, 255, 0)  # Healthy cells
RED = (255, 0, 0)  # Infected cells
GREEN2 = (0, 100, 0)  # Healthy cells not susecptible
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)  # Dead cells
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
Bgcolor = (225, 198, 153)

ScreenSize = (800, 800)
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode(ScreenSize)
pygame.display.set_caption("Covid-19 Simualtion")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

speed = [0.5, -0.5]


class Cells(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, speed, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.x_cord = random.randint(0, 400)
        self.y_cord = random.randint(50, 700)
        self.radius = 5
        self.speed = speed
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, [30, 70], self.radius, width = 0)


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 5

        #x_number = random.randint(0, 1)
        #self.xSpeed = speed[x_number]
        #y_number = random.randint(0, 1)
        #self.ySpeed = speed[y_number]


allCellsList = pygame.sprite.Group()
Cell1 = Cells(GREEN1, 5, 50, 50)
allCellsList.add(Cell1)

End = False
while not End:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            End = True

    Screen.fill(Bgcolor)
    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, BLACK, (0, 50, 400, 700), 3)
    allCellsList.update()

    allCellsList.draw(Screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I don't see where you create cell in different place. Maybe in Cell you should create method `update()` which change `self.rect`

Comment: to move Sprite you have to use (and change) `self.rect.x` `self.rect.y` but you keep position in `self.x_cord`, `self.y_cord`

Comment: your cell has size `(50,50)` and you try to draw on position `(20,70)` so it draws outside rectangle `(50, 50)` and you can't see it. You have to draw inside rectangle `(50, 50)` - for example in center `(25,25)`. And later you should use `self.rect` to move it on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your cell has size `(50,50)` and you try to draw on position `(20,70)` so it draws outside rectangle `(50, 50)` and you can't see it. You have to draw inside rectangle `(50, 50)` - for example in center `(25,25)`. And later you should use `self.rect` to move it on screen.

Second problem is that you keep position in `self.x_coord`, `self.x_coord` but you should use `self.rect.x` `self.rect.y` because `Sprite` use `self.image` and `self.rect` to draw it on screen.

And it show third problem - in Cell you need method `update` which will change values in `self.rect` to move object.

---

Minimal working example which move 5 cells in random directions.

I organize code in different way and try to use [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import random
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

GREEN1 = (0, 255, 0)  # Healthy cells
RED = (255, 0, 0)  # Infected cells
GREEN2 = (0, 100, 0)  # Healthy cells not susecptible
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)  # Dead cells
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

BACKGROUND_COLOR = (225, 198, 153)

SCREEN_SIZE = (800, 800)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# class keeep only one cell so it should has name `Cell` instead of `Cells`

class Cell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, speed, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.color = color
        self.speed = speed
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        
        self.radius = width//2 # 25 
        center = [width//2, height//2]
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, center, self.radius, width=0)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randint(0, 400)
        self.rect.y = random.randint(50, 700)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += random.randint(-10, 10)
        self.rect.y += random.randint(-10, 10)

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Covid-19 Simualtion")

speed = [0.5, -0.5]

# - objects - 

all_cells = pygame.sprite.Group()  # PEP8: lower_case_name

for _ in range(5):
    cell = Cell(GREEN1, 5, 50, 50)     # PEP8: lower_case_name
    all_cells.add(cell)

# - loop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

end = False   
while not end:

    # - events -
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            end = True

    # - upadates (without draws) -
    
    all_cells.update()

    # - draws (without updates) -
        
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 50, 400, 700), 3)
    
    all_cells.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)  # to use less CPU

# - end

pygame.quit()  # some system may need it to close window
```